# Covariant derivative of a vector field along curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma: I \rightarrow M$ be a curve, and let $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ such that $X$ is a vector field along $\gamma$. For $t \in I$, pick an orthonormal frame $\{E_1, \cdots, E_n\}$ at $\gamma(t_0)$. Then,

$\nabla_X X = \sum_{i=1}^n \dot{X}^i E_i + X^i \nabla_{\gamma’} E_i$.

I understand where $X^i \nabla_{\gamma’}E_i$ is coming from but I am not sure how to get the first expression. $\nabla_X X = \nabla_X (X^i E_i) = (\nabla_X X^i)E_i + X^i \nabla_X E_i = X(X^i)E_i + X^i \nabla_X E_i$. However, why $X(X^i) = \dot{X}^i$?

Comment: What's your reference text? I think it's from product rule .Is $\nabla_X X$ the covariant derivatives along  curve $\gamma$ ?

Comment: @SiKucing Lee’s Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds. It is corollary 8.3

Comment: Your formula looks more like the covariant derivative of $X$ along $\gamma$, that is, $\nabla_{\gamma'}X$, and after checking the book, it is this. The author writes this $D_t X$ (at least in the second edition).

Comment: @Didier I see. I still don’t understand why $X(X^i) = \dot X^i$. Do you have an insight for this?

Comment: This is because what you wrote is false: you misquoted the book.

Comment: Look at the proof of existence of covariant derivatives along a curve. In particular how it is defined locally on each chart. Then it is easy to see that the formula is true.

Comment: thank you to both of you